# unoconv convert pdf ALL pages to png

Tags: pdf, png

According to the documentation, unoconv can convert any formats that LibreOffice supports.  [Supported formats](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/)

Here is the code that tries to convert all the page of a PDF file to PNGs :

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program>python.exe unoconv -f png 
-e PageRange=1-2 klas.pdf
```

But I get the error :

```
unoconv: UnoException during export phase:
Unable to store document to file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/LibreOffice%204/p
rogram/klas.png (ErrCode 3088)
```

How can I use this **-e** option? Any working examples ?

Comment: If you are only working with PDFs then you would really be better off using Ghostscript. It's got less overhead and is specifically designed for PostScript & PDF files.

Answer (score -1):

I really recommend using something like MUPDF instead of unoconv. It has a better track record. You can see examples of how this can be done using mudraw.exe on this page:

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/Convert-PDF-documents-to-HTML4.jsp

Comment: While the intention may be helpful, this is not an answer to the question asked.